# How to ignore null/undefined value when mapping on an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can I implement this?

I want to map through the plans array and for each item render a list. while This is working, in case if we have null or undefined on a title, we still have 4 Li tag renders which the second one doesn't have any content. but how can I implement this if the title is null/undefined the object get ignored and move to next object and render the rest of the array.

Hope my explanation is clear.

```
import React from "react";


const App = (props) => {

  const plans = [
    {
      title: "Starter",
      plan: "plan_0",
    },
    { title: undefined,
      plan: "plan_1A",
    },
    {
      title: "Classic",
      plan: "plan_2A",
    },
    {
      title: "Premium",
      plan: "plan_3A",
    },
  ];


  return (
    <div>

      <h1>Notes</h1>
   
      <ul>
        {plans.map((plan, i) =>
            <li className="something" key={i}>
              <span className="somethingels">{plan.title}</span>
            </li>
        )}

      </ul>

    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

at the moment its render like this :

Starter

Classic

Premium

```
<li>Starter</li>
<li></li>
<li>Classic</li>
<li>Premium</li>
```

Comment: Add the `.filter()` method. Example `.filter((el) => el)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see that plan has a property of title before rendering a list item :)

```
  <ul>
    {plans.map(
      (plan, i) =>
        plan.title && (
          <li className="something" key={i}>
            <span className="somethingels">{plan.title}</span>
          </li>
        )
    )}
  </ul>
```

Comment: if I understand it correctly, it is like: if plan.title exists then go ahead and render it. right?

Comment: exactly  if plan.title returns truthy, then it continues to what comes after the '&&' operator. Otherwise, it will skip that chunk of code

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a conditionnal statement should do the trick :

```
    {plans.map((plan, i) =>
        { plan.title &&
            <li className="something" key={i}>
                <span className="somethingels">{plan.title}</span>
            </li>
        }
    )}
```